# Difference betwwen assign value in c:set value attribute and body attribute

Tags: jstl

Right now i am facing one serious problem. When i write following code

```
<c:set var="columnName" value="${columnObj.columnId}"/>
<c:out value="${columnRowObj[columnName]}"/>
```

i am not able to get output. here value of columnObj.columnId is 6856 and columnRowObj is resultset mapping variable.

Same above code when i write using body attribute

```
<c:set var="columnName">${columnObj.columnId}</c:set>
<c:out value="${columnRowObj[columnName]}"/>
```

i am getting output.

Anybody can please solve my problem what happens when i assign value in value attributes and when i assign it in body attribute.